# select many columns 11 sec, select just one - 2 sec

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
with my_cte as
(
...
)
select c1
from my_cte
```

this works fast (2 sec), but this

```
with my_cte as
(
...
)
select c1, c2, .. c9
from my_cte
```

works slow (11 sec).

I know you need query and execution plans, but I'm afraid I can't post them here. Perhaps you could provide some theoretical reasons for this?

**Edit**
The culprit columns seem to be nvarchar columns from a table with large number of records. I select just id from that table - it's fast, but when I select id and name - it's slow.

And from execution plans - both (fast and slow) have >50% cost from Table spool (Lazy spool), whatever that is.

Comment: You should at least elaborate to the type of columns, if they are varbinary(max) columns holding file sized data chunks, then the reason for the increased time would be obvious.

Comment: Of course it i s slower that is why you should only select columns you need. When you select more columns, there is more data to be sent over the network and more data to pull from the table.  However, it is possible the whole thing can be performance tuned but only if you tell us what the CTE does and what indexes you have onteh tables involved.

Comment: Maybe your CTE is the problem, if it already takes 2 secs to complete with id field only. The increased number of columns might just amplify the underlying problem.

Comment: @ren if there's a column that you would use frequently in your conditions, selections, then you better add an index to it as well. As HLGEM pointed out, choose what you really need.

Comment: Today's real sample: select 82 columns 1 min 52 secs, select 81 columns - 12 secs. This 1 column is of `ntext` type. So your question is most likely data-dependent - it takes more time for server to write data to storage.